# Flutter need help moving CirlceAvatar widget to the top of another container and adding text below

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new at flutter and need help moving a `CircleAvatar` widget to the top of another container and add text below in order to make a profile page.

Here is the code I currently have:

```dart
//User information section of profile
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(60),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[800],
                borderRadius:
                    const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(10))),
//Center profile picture
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 30,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                'https://test.image.com',
              ),
              child: Text('Test!'),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Can you include an image that you are trying to archive?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Column` like so:

```
Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const  EdgeInsets.all(60),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[800],
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          ),
          child: const CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30,
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              'https://test.image.com',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Text("Test!"),
      ],
    ),
```